# ArcObjects and JavaFX

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, java, javafx

I am trying to export my ESRI add-in to ArcCatalog. 
I have access to ArcGIS for Desktop. I do not use Arc Runtime.

I have created a java small program, and I'd like to kick it off with a button. 
[Here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/#2c2540f9-c2f4-4c26-9149-4ce3c6bc3784.htm) is what I used to create my button

My eclipse setup is correct.

[image]

Everything works within my IDE. If I just export this program as an .exe, it works great that way.

I'm able to export to ArcCatalog, over & over, constantly updating my version number. My add-in appears in the Add-in Manager, as per instructions found [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/java/9995022b-969a-42e9-9ae4-59020dcb9069.htm)

My program utilizes some JavaFX pop-up Vboxes. These will not open when I deploy my add-in to ArcCatalog. 
I see [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/194847-creating-a-desktop-add-in-with-javafx-and-arcobjects) and [here](https://github.com/mshareghi/arcgis-javafx-sample-addin) that I should be able to run this program via an add-in button that I've created.

I would like to ask the author of the GitHub example code (see link above) about the code in their repository. It doesn't have a main method and the JavaFX class doesn't extend Application.

Is anyone able to make this code work? What am I missing, in that I am unable to make this code run? 
The example code is offered as a public resource in GitHub.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Please add a snippet of the code you've tried that isn't doing what you're expecting